# Updating database on Django

Tags: django

Good day SO.

I want to ask something basic. I tried on my end to update my data from html to save to database but to no avail. My Model structure is Account extends to `AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager` and CompanyAccount links to Account by `OneToOneField`. I can say that my Model should have no problem since I can Register Account and Company Account without any problems.

**EDIT**

Now I can save my CompanyAccount but the link to Account was removed.
Still trying to check which is the problem

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def user_my_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    context['form_type'] = 'update'
    context['account_type'] = request.user.account_type

    if request.POST:
        if request.user.account_type == 1:
            company = CompanyAccount.objects.get(account=request.user)
            account_form = CompanyAccountForm(request.POST, instance=company)
        
        if account_form.is_valid():
            account_form.save()
            print(request.POST)
            print('SAVE')
        else:
            print('ERROR')
```

forms.py

```
class AccountCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    accuser_id      = forms.CharField(max_length=10, help_text="Required")

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ("accuser_id", "password1", "password2")

class CompanyAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyAccount
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['company_name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'content-input'})
        self.fields['company_name_kana'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'content-input'})
```

print(request.POST)

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['6zrwt68PNiJKrgZcKanDcVJkqAtogbQbNk2wHwjOzg7ybfq3Lyei9ZqdbmAJcYrV'], 'company_name': ['TESTING'], ....etc
```

This part here, it does print SAVE on my terminal but it does not save to the database.

Comment: Is your view returning a response? Can you share the rest of your view? If you have `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` set to `True` and you don't return a valid response the form won't save

Comment: I got it.
from `account_form = CompanyAccountForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)`
to `account_form = CompanyAccountForm(request.POST, instance=company )`
But there is another problem. My link to Account was removed.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Created a new Form for update then excluded the Account.

```
class CompanyAccountUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyAccount
        fields = "__all__"
        exclude = ('account',)
```

Then used the new Form to my update view

Comment: You can only use `exclude` instead of using both `fields` and `exclude`

Comment: Oh. did not know that. Will update rn. Thank you for the advice